# SQLite simplify union of left outer join

Tags: sql, sqlite

I inherited some monster SQL queries and I would like to simplify/ shorten them as much as possible.

One of them is:

```
SELECT 
              * 
            FROM 
              (
                SELECT 
                  $columnsFromBothTables
                FROM 
                  table_abc
                  left outer join table_xyz using profile_id 
                union 
                select 
                  $columnsFromBothTables
                from 
                  table_xyz 
                  left outer join table_abc using profile_id
              )
```

It looks weirdly redundant.
Is there a way to simplify it to sth like?

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT $columns FROM table_abc MAGIC_OPERATION table_xyz
)
```

Isn't it a FULL OUTER JOIN?

**Updates**:
My understanding is that both tables have M-1 relationship to "profile" table.

They do not have direct relationship to each other

Comment: Something like FULL OUTER JOIN, which is not supported by SQLite.

Comment: A FULL OUTER JOIN also needs a NOT EXISTS.

Comment: Are you sure it's some other column and not the same column? That doesn't at all look redundant to me then and is not a full outer join either. What columns are selected? Is it twice the same columns? Columns from both tables?

Comment: Colums of both tables @ThorstenKettner

Comment: This answers only one of my questions. And the `USING` clauses are on different columns? And the selected columns are exactly the same in both queries? And yet another question: How many abc rows per xyz row? 0 to n or 0 to 1? And vice versa?

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenKettner, I've just updated my question. Hope it's clearer now

Comment: Provided $columnsFromBothTables are exactly the same for both queries and provided neither query produces duplicate $columnsFromBothTables, then yes, this is a full outer join emulation. In that case Gordon's approach with `UNION ALL` and `IS NULL` is better, because it does the same, but with less work for the DBMS.

Comment: It is possible that this query produces more rows than necessary or is even faulty. But we cannot know tha of course. Full outer joins are a very rare thing and joining two tables that are not directly related can produce combinations one is not really interested in. An example: If for posts I have one table with likes and one with dislikes and I join the two on the post ID, then I'll combine every like with every dislike per post, i.e. for 5 likes and 6 dislikes I'll create 5x6=30 nonsensical combinations. Maybe `UNION` is a means here to get rid of involuntarily generated redundant data

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to but not exactly a `full outer join`.  I would recommend this approach for the `full outer join`:

```
select $columns
from abc left join
     xyz
     on . . .
union all
select $columns
from xyz left join
     abc
     on . . .
where abc.? is null;  -- some column to validate that there is no match
```

Note:  This does not remove duplicates -- which your code does.  That is why this version should perform better.  But it might not do exactly what you want.

Comment: Is the "on" equivalent of "using" in my Sqlite query?

Comment: @ericn: `USING` is an alternative to `ON` in standard SQL and in SQLite, too. You can use it only when the columns in the clause have the same names in the tables. `ON` is more flexible hence, because this restriction does not apply.

Comment: What is the motivation for `union all` instead of `union`. Does it have to do with your note "This does not remove duplicates -- which your code does"?

Comment: @ericn . . . Yes.  `union` both slows the query down (to remove duplicates) and makes the logic different from a `full join`.